# Updating firebase database (iOS, swift) with multiple fields without overriding existing data

Tags: swift, firebase

This has been answered with reference to updating single fields but not multiple fields.

When a user registers in my app I write to firebase database a list of fields. The root of the firebase database is users and each user node is a specified unique username.

```
-users
     -username  
        "name"
        "title"
        "date of birth"
        "location"
        "about"
        "height"
```

In UpdateDetailsController is a user update page where they can update some of these fields:

```
 let key = model.ref.child("users").child(currentLoggedInUser).key

     let post = [
                        "name": name.text!,
                        "title": title.text!,
                        "about": about.text! ]
            let childUpdates = ["\(key)": post]

            model.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

While the username remains the same using ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates) overrides the whole node so it looks like:

```
 -users
         -username  
            "name"
            "title"
            "about"
```

Advice would be appreciated!

Thx.

Comment: it will override everything that you have in the dictionary that you are trying to save... are you saying that `(location, height, about)` get updated as well ?

Comment: @Lamar i Think OP already knows that, hence why he is asking for help

Comment: Your use of `model.ref` seems inconsistent.  When getting the username (key), you use  `model.ref.child("users")`. So shouldn't the update be `model.ref.child("users").updateChildValues(childUpdates)`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. At registration time there are 6 fields under the username node....and then when the user does the update those 6 fields are overriden so there are only 3 fields under the node: name, title and about.

Comment: I understand the unexpected result you think you are seeing.  You're using the correct update method, as shown in the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).  My comment was:  Is the code you posted really updating location `/users/$username/`?  It looks like it's updating /$username.

Comment: Hi @Bob. Thanks. Yeah it actually is updating /users/$username .... I just tested it again. But it's obviously not "updating" it's "overwriting" - I need to have a look back at my code and figure out why. In the init() of my Singleton I iniitliase the firebase database reference as -       ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users"). I'm not sure if that's the either the right place to initialise the db or the whether I need the (withPath: "users").

Comment: Hi @Bob the answer below worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
model.ref.child(key).updateChildValues(post)
```

Comment: Too easy. Thanks! Would you mind explaining the difference between that line and this: let childUpdates = ["\(key)": post], model.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates) which is obviously not correct.

Comment: Long story short you are basically updating the User node instead of the username node. I have a feeling that `model.ref.child("users").updateChildValues(childUpdates)` will work as well if you wanted to keep your current flow?